# Grep a specific column

Tags: text-formatting

I have the following output:

```
Created                 LabelNum Size   Retention Hostname                Location Label           Plugin               Expires                 Server
----------------------- -------- ------ --------- ----------------------- -------- --------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------
2017-03-22 01:43:29 IST 9        1.0 GB DW        vdp-dest.happycow.local Local    A-1490127173251 Windows VMware Image 2017-03-26 01:42:53 IST DD - data-domain.happycow.local
```

I would like to grep contents under the `Expires` column
The value under this will change from client to client so this will be a variable.

So, regardless of what value is there, I would like to see the output. In this case it should be:

```
Expires
-----------------------
2017-03-26 01:42:53 IST
```

Comment: if your fields are tab-delimited, `awk -F'\t' ' $9 ~ /pattern/ {print}'`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a fixed column and then it is:

```
cut -c121-143 file
```

Edit:

Another way to do it if the column with the key word 'Expires' can vary, is by first identify the position of the keyword and then echo from that position and 23 ahead:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Syntax:
#   ./cut_expires < file
#
# read first line from stdin
read LINE
# Remove chars from start to 'Expires' inclusive
PREFIX=${LINE/*Expires/}
EXPIRES=Expires
# Calculate where 'Expires' start
START=$(( ${#LINE}-${#PREFIX}-${#EXPIRES} ))
echo $EXPIRES
while read LINE; do
    # echo from character pos $START and 23 characters
    echo ${LINE:$START:23}
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the value under this are not fixed. This varies from VM to VM and from machine to machine. Basically I am trying to extent the expiration date via a script by adding days. So the expiration date changes depending on when a backup was taken, so it is never fixed.

Comment: I guessed the date could change but does the column also change? The command above is fairly simple, it just take all characters from position 121 to 143. Pls add how line 2 and 3 would look in your original question.